# teradata select within the past 10 minutes from current

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to check the log every 10 minutes for specific activity within that 10 minute interval.

I think that means I want a WHERE clause to say something like `WHERE logtime > CURRENT_TIME - interval '10' MINUTE;` but I'm getting *Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.*

Here's where I'm at losing this battle. Is it because logtime needs different formatting?

```
SELECT username (TITLE ''),
     logdate (FORMAT 'YYYY/MM/DD', TITLE ''),
     logtime (CHAR(11), TITLE ''),
     event (TITLE '')
FROM TERA_LOG_VIEWS.LogonOff_Today
WHERE event <> 'logoff'
AND logtime > CURRENT_TIME - interval '10' MINUTE
ORDER BY 2,3;
```

**update**

I am getting closer thanks to some helpful comments. I have the 10 minute range I'm looking for, except somehow I am on the previous hour.

`CURRENT_TIME` alone is showing correctly at the 16th hour, but when I run it in this SQL the results are a 10 minute window of the 15th hour. I am confused as to why.

```
SELECT username (TITLE ''),
     logdate (FORMAT 'YYYY/MM/DD', TITLE ''),
     Cast(Trim(LogTime) AS TIME(2)),
     event (TITLE '')
FROM TERA_LOG_VIEWS.LogonOff_Today
WHERE event <> 'logoff'
AND logdate = CURRENT_DATE
AND Cast(Trim(LogTime) AS TIME(2)) BETWEEN (CURRENT_TIME - interval '10' MINUTE) and CURRENT_TIME
ORDER BY 2,3;
```

This is what seems to get me what I wanted. But I have no idea why it was necessary to + an hour.

```
SELECT username (TITLE ''),
     logdate (FORMAT 'YYYY/MM/DD', TITLE ''),
     Cast(Trim(LogTime) AS TIME(2)),
     event (TITLE '')
FROM TERA_LOG_VIEWS.LogonOff_Today
WHERE event <> 'logoff'
AND logdate = CURRENT_DATE
AND Cast(Trim(LogTime) AS TIME(2)) BETWEEN (CURRENT_TIME - interval '10' MINUTE + interval '1' HOUR) and CURRENT_TIME + interval '1' HOUR
ORDER BY 2,3;
```

Comment: The datatype of dbc.LogonOffV.LogTime is FLOAT, you need to cast it to a TIME: `Cast(Trim(LogTime) AS TIME(2))`

Comment: And just in principle, it's typically better to use TIMESTAMP (date/time) datatype for this type of comparison rather than TIME alone.

Comment: Thank you both. I have changed the logtime part to ```Cast(Trim(LogTime) AS TIME(2)),``` I am able to get results from commenting out the interval clause. But I believe my main issue is with this interval line since I'm still getting *Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.* in response with it uncommented.

Comment: The +1 hour is probably related to your system/session time zone.